# Burning damage in Savage Worlds

Tags: savage-worlds, supers, necessary-evil

I will soon start a game of Necessary Evil, and one of my players will have the Elemental Attack (fire) superpower, and I am not completely sure if I understand the rules correctly.

> Anytime something ﬂammable is hit by fire, roll 1d6. On a 6, the target catches fire

After a hit I roll a d12 (rules from the superpower, normally it would be d6) and check if the result is 6 or more to see it the enemy catches fire. If yes the enemy gets one stack of "burning".

According to the Necessary Evil rules, I have to improve the flammability rating by one step instead of rolling a d12:

> Each round after a victim catches fire (at
>   the beginning of his action), roll as if checking
>   to see if the victim catches fire again. If he
>   does, the fire grows in intensity and does its
>   current level +2 in damage that round. This
>   is cumulative to +6.
>
> *Savage Worlds Explorers Edition, page 104*

So I now have a burning drone with a toughness of 8 (2) that has one stack of burning. I now check with a d6 if he gets another stack, which he does not. Afterwards I calculate the burning damage for this round to be 3 points of damage, which is ignored as the toughness of the drone is higher.

For the fire to be effective it has to be stacked 4 times to deal the maximum damage of 6 and then automatically kills the drone (first round shaken, then a wound in the second one).

On the next page it says that I get 1d10 points of damage for a "spot fire", such as a burning arm or leg. Does that mean that a burning foe gets 1d10 + levels of burning + 2 points of damage each round?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rules for fire damage have been updated and simplified a little. The ones you're using are from the *Explorer's Edition* (2007), the newest are from the *Deluxe Edition* (2011). I would suggest you use the newest version. The key difference is that they've got rid of the 'cumulative+2 bit'. The basics are...

- Fire damage always happens at the beginning of the round
- At the beginning of the round immediately after you catch fire, you take 1d10 damage, as the fire is only a spot fire
- At the beginning of each round that you stay on fire you also roll d6. On a 6, the fire spreads, increasing in intensity
- The three levels of intensity are 1d10 for a spot fire, 2d10, then 3d10

For example:

- Round 1: You are struck by a flaming weapon. As well as taking the weapon's normal damage you roll d6 and get a 6. This means you are now on fire, with intensity 1d10
- Round 2: At the start of the round you take 1d10 damage. You then roll d6 to see if the fire spreads. You roll a 6, so it does, increasing in intensity. During your round you fail to put out the fire
- Round 3: You take 2d10 damage, then roll d6. You roll 4, so it doesn't increases in intensity. You fail to put out the fire
- Round 4: You take another 2d10 damage. This time you roll a d6, so it increases in intensity again to its highest possible level
- Additional rounds: You take 3d10 damage at the start of each round until you put the fire out or die, as it is now at its highest intensity